# bash - test MM between 01 and 12

Tags: bash

I have $MM. It can be:
01-12

But not 1-12 (i.e. every single digit will have a 0 in front, 1=01, 2=02 etc.)

I need to write a test that ensures that MM is valid, and fail if not. I have tried:

```
MM=09
if [[ "$MM" -le 0 ]] && [[ "$MM" -ge 13 ]]; then
  echo "MM is not between 01 and 12"
fi
```

errors:

```
[[: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

I have also tried various combinations:

```
MM=13
if [ $MM -le 0 ] && [ $MM -ge 13 ]; then
  echo "MM is not between 01 and 12"
fi
```

shows nothing when MM is 13 (to be expected)

```
MM=13
if [ $MM <= 0 ] && [ $MM => 13 ]; then
  echo "MM is not between 01 and 12"
fi
```

errors

```
=: No such file or directory
```

I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong here, I'm just not sure what it is. I also need this logic to apply similar checks for:

DD needs to be between 01-31
hh needs to be between 00-23
mm needs to be between 00-59

thanks!

Comment: Prefix `0` means the number will be octal; digits `8` and `9` do not exist in octal system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all leading 0 makes shell interpret it as octal number and `09` is invalid octal so you will get: `09: value too great for base` error.

You can use use BASH regex for this validation:

```
mm='09'

[[ $mm =~ ^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$ ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
valid

mm='9'
[[ $mm =~ ^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$ ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
invalid

mm='13'
[[ $mm =~ ^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$ ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
invalid

mm='12'
[[ $mm =~ ^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$ ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
valid
```

Comment: could you explain why `[[ $MM =~ ^(0[1-9]|[10-12])$ ]] ` doesn't work when MM=11?

Comment: `mm='11' && [[ $mm =~ ^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$ ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"` prints `valid` for me

Comment: yes that works fine. I'm just curious as to why `[10-12]` doesn't work.

Comment: `[10-12]` doesn't mean match all numbers between `10` and `12`. Refer this good tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use arithmetic comparison, specifying the radix:

```
if (( 10#$mm < 1 || 10#$mm > 12 )); then
  echo "mm is not between 1 and 12"
fi
```

or, similarly,

```
if (( 10#$mm >= 1 && 10#$mm <= 12 )); then
  echo "mm is between 1 and 12"
fi
```

You specify the radix by using `radix#` in front of the number/variable expansion. Here we need radix 10, hence the `10#` in front of the expansion `$mm`. See [*Shell Arithmetic* in the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) (near the end of the section).

The other answer (with regexes) is good, but doesn't carry the proper semantic, and can be really awkward with more complicated ranges.

Comment: But this doesn't ensure that the field is always two characters (zero-padded if necessary).  Maybe add a separate check for that.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want `sh` compatibility, the `case` statement is handy.

```
case $MM in ? | ???* | *[!0-9]* | 1[3-9] | [2-9]? | 00) echo Invalid;; esac
```

This triggers on, in turn, too short, too long, non-numeric, too large smaller than 20, other too large numbers, and all zeros.